# Viber gives error during installation

Tags: 16.04, viber

Double clicking viber.deb doesn't install it so I tried terminal which also gives errors(translated with google translate):

```
dmitriy @ dmitriy-ub16x64: ~ / Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
[sudo] password for dmitriy:
Selecting a previously unselected viber package.
(Reading the database ... at the moment there are 585858 files and directories installed.)
Preparing for unpacking viber.deb ...
Unpacked viber (7.0.0.1035) ...
dpkg: package dependencies do not allow you to configure the viber package:
 viber depends on gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, however:
  The package gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is not installed.
 viber depends on gstreamer1.0-libav, however:
  The package gstreamer1.0-libav is not installed.

dpkg: error while processing the viber package (--install):
 dependency problems - leave unconfigured
Triggers are being processed for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Triggers are being processed for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Triggers are being processed for bamfdaemon (0.5.3 ~ bzr0 + 16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index ...
Triggers are handled for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Triggers are handled for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
The following errors occurred while processing the following packages:
 viber
dmitriy @ dmitriy-ub16x64: ~ / Downloads $ sudo apt-get gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
E: Invalid gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly operation
dmitriy @ dmitriy-ub16x64: ~ / Downloads $ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
Reading Package Lists ... Done
Building a Dependency Tree
Reading status information ... Done
Perhaps to correct these errors you will want to use "apt-get -f install":
Packages with unsatisfied dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly: Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr (= 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1) but it will not be installed
                             Depends: libmpg123-0 (> = 1.6.2) but it will not be installed
                             Depends: libsidplay1v5 but it will not be installed
 viber: Depends: gstreamer1.0-libav but it will not be installed
E: Unsatisfied dependencies. Try executing "apt-get -f install" without specifying the package name, (or find another solution).
```

Do I go with `apt-get -f install` or can it cause some damage to this Ubuntu 16.04 x64?

Comment: Yes, run `sudo apt-get -f install`, and then the `dpkg -i ...` command again.

Comment: thank you it worked! though Viber window which opened is bigger than my 1920x1080 screen, can't see bottom buttons. I assume it's a very early alpha on Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu comes with libcurl4 library, but Viber says that the dependancy is libcurl3.

You have to install Viber without one of the depencancies. The correct way to install Viber is this:
You freeze libcurl4,
ignore the Viber dependancy libcurl3 and install Viber with a force flag,
then unfreeze libcurl4:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libcurl4
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libcurl3 ~/viber.deb
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libcurl3 ~/viber.deb
sudo apt-mark unhold libcurl4
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Excellent first answer!  Upvoted already and you're a rep 11 user already!